# Bootstrap Scroll Spy not working.Shows only the home state active but doesnt change to other states when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollspy

This is my html and css.please help me with the scrollspy as I dont know what exactly is the problem .If possible let me know the code you have written to solve the problem

MY HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default center navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">

  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up"type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">&#9776;</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>

    <div class="navbar-inner">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" data-target="#jumbotron">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-target="#about">ABOUT</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-target="#skills">SKILLS</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</nav>

<div class=" jumbotron" id="jumbotron"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="skills"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

MY CSS

and the divs are of 750px in heights

```
  body
  {

    background: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', Georgia, Times, serif;

  }
  /* --------------------------------------------Navbar CSS--------------------------------------------------- */

  .navbar-default 
  {
    background-color: #610B0B ;
    border-radius:0px;

  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a 
  {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;

    font-family: 'Droid Serif', Georgia, Times, serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 3px 10px -3px 10px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 8px;

  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
  { 
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus 
  {
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
  }
```

Comment: <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="200">.

Comment: the above comment is the scrollspy code.

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting code in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong.

First, 3 of your `nav-link` anchors have `data-target=` when they should have `href=`

Second, you need to set the `data-target=` to the `<body>` of the navbar. This allows Javascript to find what to target with Scrollspy:

```
<body data-target="#navbar">
```

and third, if you haven't, you need to call Scrollspy via Javascript:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar' })
```

Here is a Codepen with a working example:

http://codepen.io/charliebeckstrand/pen/NrWpXP

Comment: hey made the changes you told me to make but still not working.In the<body> what all should I write .

Comment: Wrap all of the HTML, starting with the navbar in a <body data-target="#navbar"> tag.

Comment: and at the end of the body, after all of your divs, put <script>$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar' })</script>

Comment: still not working...nd different change you made in the code

Comment: Are you loading jQuery into your project?

Comment: can i get your email id i send my entire filr

Comment: Use this website: https://jsfiddle.net/. Once you paste in all of your code, you can click share. Copy the link and share that here.

Comment: It is not responsive sorry fot that.But i pasted the whole code

Comment: That's fine. Scrollspy is working in your jsfiddle if jQuery and the Bootstrap JS file are loaded in.

Comment: Add these to the bottom of your file: 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Those are using the Bootstrap CDN for jQuery and the Bootstrap Javascript file. If you have them in your project you can use relative paths instead.

Comment: these are the <link> and <script> i have used..I have pasted it in javascript column

Comment: Okay. I found it. Bootstrap 4 requires "nav-tabs" or "nav-pills" to be added to your nav for it to work. Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24dfabru/5/

Comment: Sorry that was such a comprehensive process. I wasn't aware that you were using Bootstrap 4, which does things slightly differently.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.It is working fine.But the reason I didn't use nav-pills is because I couldn't change the color of the pills from default blue to anything else.Can you please help me with that last color change thing.

Comment: Add this to your CSS: #navbar .nav-pills .nav-item.open .nav-link,
#navbar .nav-pills .nav-item.open .nav-link:focus,
#navbar .nav-pills .nav-item.open .nav-link:hover,
#navbar .nav-pills .nav-link.active,
#navbar .nav-pills .nav-link.active:focus,
#navbar .nav-pills .nav-link.active:hover {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #555555;
}

Comment: Or here is a link with the pills styled the way you wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/24dfabru/7/

Comment: I find it difficult to make custom styling in bootstarp.Any suggestions where I can learn that from.Any website,book,pdf.

Comment: I'm experiencing a weird behaviour when I intitialize Bootstrap 5 scrollspy from JS. Indeed, despite the fact I set a dummy target selector (`$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#dummy-bar' })`), my scrollspy gets initialized correctly (links get an active class when I scroll the page).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in bootstrap 5 and downloaded [bootstrap 4.3.1](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js)
and replace it with previous version.